# (Discord.py) How do I make a command that gives you a role that's specified?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code a command in discord.py that when called, will give you a role called "DJ"

Here's my current code:

```
@client.command
async def role(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="DJ")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

It is also worth noting that this bot is in 2 servers, one of which does not have the DJ role in the server. Is that a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you use discord.py rewrite?

Comment: @Nurqm I'm not sure, but I have discord.py 1.5.1 and downloaded it through `pip install discord.py`. Do you have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something similar to

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
   await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```